How to fetch the query URL in Astro?
I'm trying to filter blog pages using query and parsing. I've found the problem to be this block of code:
// URL logged here
console.log("URL:", Astro.request.url);

const url = new URL(Astro.request.url);
 
for (const [key, value] of url.searchParams) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

Request url is always http://localhost:4321/blog.
When the new page is queried, the new url is loaded in the browser, but the url remains the same in the terminal, so obviously its not being fetched correctly.
I've looked through the docs but cant find anything. Thanks
Due to Astro nature, I'm not sure whats causing the problem, and what's the next step. Any help is more than welcome.

Have you tried
const queryString = window.location.search;
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

Query wont work because Astro by default is a Static Site Generator.
Enabling a SSR with an adapter fixes the issue.
